# Dovecot auto folder creation "Unknown setting: mailbox"

Tags: amazon-ec2, dovecot, spamassasin

First off my dovecot info:

```
$ dovecot --version
2.0.9
```

Running on an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance.

I've added this in my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/virtual/%d/%n

namespace {
    separator = /
    prefix =
    inbox = yes
}
```

This all works, then following numerous guides I try to add a Junk or SPam folder automatically, by changing the conf to:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/virtual/%d/%n

namespace {
    separator = /
    prefix =
    inbox = yes
    mailbox Spam {
      auto = create # autocreate Spam, but don't autosubscribe
      special_use = \Junk
    }
}
```

But restarting dovecot gives `Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf line 41: Unknown setting: mailbox`

I've found some other people with the same issue but no answers. This seems crazily simple and impossible. Any pointers are very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like v2.1 of Dovecot is where this got enabled, so the amazon repo has an older version.